# Update context value after API call

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React 16.3 Context API, I'm setting `loggedin: bool` & `user: Object` value using context, also using `PrivateRoute` for logged in user.

Here is a brief code.

```
// AuthContext JS
import React from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

class AuthProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            user      : null
        };

        this.setAuth = this.setAuth.bind(this);
    };

    setAuth(isLoggedIn = false, userData = null) {
        this.setState({
            isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
            user      : userData
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider
                value={ {...this.state, setAuth: this.setAuth} }>
                { this.props.children }
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

const AuthUser = AuthContext.Consumer;

export {AuthContext, AuthProvider, AuthUser};
```

---

```
function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...rest}) {
    return (
        <AuthUser>
            {
                ({isLoggedIn}) => (
                    <Route
                        { ...rest }
                        render={ props =>
                            (
                                isLoggedIn ? (
                                    <Component { ...props } />
                                ) : (
                                    <Redirect
                                        to={ {
                                            pathname: "/login",
                                            state   : {from: props.location}
                                        } }
                                    />
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    />
                )
            }
        </AuthUser>
    );
}

// App JS
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <AuthProvider>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={ Login } />
                        <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" component={ Register } />
                        <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" component={ Page404 } />
                        <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" component={ Page500 } />

                        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={ DefaultLayout } />
                    </Switch>
                </AuthProvider>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

---

```
// Login JS
class Login extends Component {
    handleSubmit(values) {
        const opts = {
            "email"   : "test@example.com",
            "password": "test123"
        };

        let _this = this;

        fetch("API_URL", {
            method: "post",
            body  : JSON.stringify(opts)
        })
            .then(
                (response) => {
                    return response.json();
                }
            ).then(
            (data) => {
                _this.setState({
                    isAuth: true,
                    user  : data.data.user
                });
                _this.props.history.replace("/dashboard");

            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.isAuth);
        return (
            <AuthUser>
                {
                    ({isLoggedIn, setAuth}) =>
                       (
                                    <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
                                ) : ( <div > // Login Page </div>
                       )
                }
            </AuthUser>
        );
    }
}
```

How do I update/call `setAuth` function of consumer

If I call `setAuth` from render function, it will give warning & loop over `setState`

Any Help!

Answer (score 1):

In the `handleSubmit` function in the `Login` file, instead of calling
    this.setState({
        isAuth: true,
        user: data.data.user
    });
you should call the `setAuth` function provided by the context and update the user auth and data in the context there:

```
this.context.setAuth(true, data.data.user)
```

In order to use `this.context`, you may need to change from using context consumer to `contextType`:

```
static contextType = AuthContext
```

Answer (score 0):

You have implement a higher order component that help component consume context value as props.

The following `withContextAsProps` HOC provides an example:

```
function withContextAsProps(Context, Component) {
    function WithContextAsProps(prop) {
       return (
         <Context>
          {value => <Component {...value} />}
         </Context>
       );
    }
    const componentName = Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Component';
    const contextName = Context.displayName || Context.name || 'Context';
    WithContextAsProps.displayName = `With${contextName}Context(${componentName})`;
    return WithContextAsProps;
}
```

In `Login` component, the HOC can be used to make `isAuth` and `setAuth` value from `AuthUser` context consumer available as `props` in the `Login` component.

```
class Login extends Component {
  handleSubmit = values => {
     //...

    fetch("API_URL", {
        method: "post",
        body  : JSON.stringify(opts)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(
          data => {
            this.props.setAuth(true, data.data.user);
            this.props.location.assign("/dashboard");

        }
    );
  }                       

  render() {
    return this.props.isAuth ?
                      <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
                      : <div>Login Page</div>;
  }
}

export default withContextAsProps(AuthUser, Login);
```